# Cannot connect to Postgres from remote address

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I cannot connect from my machine to a server running Postgres. I think I've configured it all correctly. No firewall are present on the server.

I'm running Postgres 9.1.9 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

This is from /etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_hba.conf

```
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

local   all             all                                     peer
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

I have `listen_addresses = '*'` in /etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf

I've stopped and started the service multiple times.

`netstat -tulnp`:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:27017           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      19312/mongod    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:28017           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      19312/mongod    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      978/sshd        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      30239/postgres  
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      978/sshd        
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN      30239/postgres
```

My iptable is empty.

When I try to connect to the server with

```
psql -U postgres -h <MY_IP>
```

I get:

```
psql: could not connect to server: Operation timed out
Is the server running on host "<MY_IP>" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Any help? Thanks

**EDIT**

tcpdump on port 5432:

```
16:33:10.548507 7c:c3:a1:a2:d9:27 (oui Unknown) > 00:00:5e:00:01:01 (oui Unknown), ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 78: <MY_MAC> > <MY_SERVER>.postgresql: Flags [S], seq 95915852, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 4,nop,nop,TS val 1189142453 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
```

Comment: Did you check intermediate firewalls for blocking traffic on that port? Can you ping the server-machine from the client machine? Check with tcpdump if the traffic reaches the server `tcpdump -i ethX -e 'port 5432'`

Comment: updated the post: 16:33:10.548507 7c:c3:a1:a2:d9:27 (oui Unknown) > 00:00:5e:00:01:01 (oui Unknown), ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 78: <MY_MAC> > <MY_SERVER>.postgresql: Flags [S], seq 95915852, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 4,nop,nop,TS val 1189142453 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0

Comment: Can you connect to it at localhost? `psql -U postgres -h localhost`?  Can you telnet to the server? `telnet <YOUR_IP> 5432`?

Comment: it works on localhost but i cannot telnet to it

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8090458/remote-access-to-postgresql-database ?

Comment: as stated, i already have listen_addresses = '*' and i restarted multiple times

Comment: This may be farfetched, but I had this constellation once in real live, the syptoms were as you describe it (our problem was with ssh connections): The TCP dump shows timestamps; can you disable tcp-timestamps on the client and test that further (`echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_timestamps` on a linux machine)?

Comment: The fact that you can connect with localhost but not with <YOUR_IP> indicates some network issues reaching your server.  I would start by trying to ping <YOUR_IP>.  If that fails, it is very likely something on your network blocking the connection.  If not, start trying to connect from "close" to the server and work your way out (ie, use LAN IP on the server machine, then LAN IP on another local machine, then public IP on another local machine, etc).  The point at which the connection fails will hopefully give you more info. about the problem.

Comment: Offtopic, ok -- Migrate it to server fault then?